# API v4 : Caught Exception: Invalid Field

Tags: apiv4

the CiviCRM version I'm using is 5.52.3 (Wordpress), I have created an API v4 to retrieve Contact under a PHP code and was put in shortcode in one of the page under Wordpress. It was working fine, I found out that after a while with no activities, when I tried to search again, it issued API v4 : Caught Exception: Invalid Field ....  I logout and login again, it works again. I suspect it is a timeout problem, is it a timeout parameter I can set in one of the PHP? Another question is do you have an example how to code the throw exception of API (v4)? Thanks for your attention.